# InApp Billing and never get com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED

Tags: android, in-app-billing

on a Samsung, running on android 2.1-update I never get com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED.

The android market is running, running, but never answer to my application about the PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED.

I find a post on the android forum http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/468004148f3e341b
where it seems to be a problem notice on other 2.1 device.

I have got to other devices running on android 2.2 and 2.3.
I don't face any problem.

Do you notice the same problem on android 2.1 ?

I do my test with "android.test.purchased" item

Answer (score 0):

I've just been having the same problem. After working fine for some time the PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED broadcast wasn't coming though.

To fix I cleared the data and cache of the Market app in Settings->Applications->Manage Applications. I also had to open the market app once and accept the agreement otherwise it was returning in app billing unavailable.